# d3 v6 add label to the Nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to add the `id` to the nodes of the graph in the example of

https://d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/network_basic.html

I tried

```
...
node.append("text")
    .attr("dx", 12)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name });
...
```

but the name does not appear

how can I add the name next to the node

Answer (score 1):

The `node` variable represents a selection of SVG circles, which cannot contain text elements. You have to use a group element as a parent to hold the circle and the text elements.

First create a selection of group elements that the force simulation will place:

```
const nodes = svg
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(data.nodes)
  .join("g");
```

Then add your circle and your text in the groups:

```
nodes.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 20)
  .style("fill", "#69b3a2")

nodes.append("text")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle") // text is centered in the circle
  .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")
  .text(d => d.name);
```

Because the force simulation works on group elements, the `ticked()` function must be adapted to translate them:

```
nodes.attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.x+6},${d.y-6})`);
```

See example here: https://codepen.io/ccasenove/pen/eYKzmwd